# How to detect with python if the string contains html code?

Tags: python, html, parsing, detect

How to detect either the string contains an html (can be html4, html5, just partials of html within text)? I do not need a version of HTML, but rather if the string is just a text or it contains an html. Text is typically multiline with also empty lines

## Update:

example inputs:

html:

```
<head><title>I'm title</title></head>
Hello, <b>world</b>
```

non-html:

```
<ht fldf d><
<html><head> head <body></body> html
```

Comment: why do you need to know?  what are you planning on doing differently?

Comment: just detecting if the string contains html, then either remove string or print it out

Answer (score 57):

You can use an HTML parser, like [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Note that it really tries it best to parse an HTML, even broken HTML, it can be very and not very lenient depending on the [underlying parser](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = """<html>
... <head><title>I'm title</title></head>
... </html>"""
>>> non_html = "This is not an html"
>>> bool(BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser").find())
True
>>> bool(BeautifulSoup(non_html, "html.parser").find())
False
```

This basically tries to find any html element inside the string. If found - the result is `True`.

Another example with an HTML fragment:

```
>>> html = "Hello, <b>world</b>"
>>> bool(BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser").find())
True
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html):

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> html = 'Hello, <b>world</b>'
>>> non_html = "<ht fldf d><"
>>> lxml.html.fromstring(html).find('.//*') is not None
True
>>> lxml.html.fromstring(non_html).find('.//*') is not None
False
```

Comment: what about `non-html = "<html><head> head <body></body> html"` `bool(BeautifulSoup(non_html, "html.parser").find())
=> True`? It is not an html snippet

Comment: even `non_html = "<html head> head <body jdkjs /body> html dkslfjglangaiowmgiowe"` will pass the test :(

Comment: @static well, this would be `True`, cause `BeautifulSoup` tries it best to parse the html and be lenient. It would transform it to `<html><head> head <body></body> html</head></html>`.

Comment: it is nice, that it passes many problematic cases through, but it looks, that it passes too much through: `non_html = "<ht fldf d><"` will also work

Comment: @static yeah, in this case it thinks `fldf` and `d` are attributes and `ht` tag is just not closed. Nice examples, thanks :)

Comment: @static I've added an alternative solution, please check if it works for you.

Comment: Note that `BeautifulSoup('This is not an html', 'lxml').find()` returns `<html><body><p>This is not an html</p></body></html>` - so use `html.parser`.

Comment: `lxml.html.fromstring('<img src="http://example.com"/>').find('.//*') is not None` returns false. Shouldn't it be true?

Answer (score 8):

One way I thought of was to intersect start and end tags found by attempting to parse the text as HTML and intersecting this set with a known set of acceptable HTMl elements.

**Example:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function

from HTMLParser import HTMLParser


from html5lib.sanitizer import HTMLSanitizerMixin


class TestHTMLParser(HTMLParser):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.elements = set()

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        self.elements.add(tag)

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        self.elements.add(tag)


def is_html(text):
    elements = set(HTMLSanitizerMixin.acceptable_elements)

    parser = TestHTMLParser()
    parser.feed(text)

    return True if parser.elements.intersection(elements) else False


print(is_html("foo bar"))
print(is_html("<p>Hello World!</p>"))
print(is_html("<html><head><title>Title</title></head><body><p>Hello!</p></body></html>"))  # noqa
```

**Output:**

```
$ python foo.py
False
True
True
```

This works for partial text that contains a subset of HTML elements.

**NB:** This makes use of the [html5lib](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/html5lib) so it may not work for other document types necessarily but the technique can be adapted easily.

Comment: It's basically the same solution as yours -- just a different library and using set intersection of known elements :P

Comment: I don't find `HTMLSanitizerMixin` anymore in html5lib.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily extend the built-in [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html#html.parser.HTMLParser) that already handles the parsing, and collect (start/end) `tags`, `attrs`, and `data`. To assert whether the document is valid the amount of start tags should match the amount of end tags:

```py
from html.parser import HTMLParser


class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.start_tags = list()
        self.end_tags = list()
        self.attributes = list()
    
    def is_text_html(self):
        return len(self.start_tags) == len(self.end_tags)

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        self.start_tags.append(tag)
        self.attributes.append(attrs)

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        self.end_tags.append(tag)

    def handle_data(self, data):
        print("Encountered some data  :", data)
```

Then

```
>>> parser = MyHTMLParser()
>>> parser.feed("<head><title>I'm title</title></head>"
                "Hello, <b>world</b>")
>>> parser.is_text_html()

True

>>> parser.feed("<ht fldf d><"
                "<html><head> head <body></body> html")
>>> parser.is_text_html()

False
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you need to know is wether or not a string contains html text then another solution not listed here would be to use a regex expression like the following:

`</?\s*[a-z-][^>]*\s*>|(\&(?:[\w\d]+|#\d+|#x[a-f\d]+);)`

Bear in mind that although this would be a much faster solution than using an HTML Parser, it can be potentially inaccurate depending on the complexity of html markup you're expecting.

[Here is a test](https://regex101.com/r/Va987X/1) of the above regex for a general idea of it's coverage.

Answer (score -4):

Check for ending tags. This is simplest and most robust I believe.

```
"</html>" in possibly_html
```

If there is an ending html tag, then it looks like html, otherwise not so much.

Comment: This is a good answer, assuming the input is a complete HTML page (has `</html>` in it. It won't work for partial HTML (like `<b>some word</b>`).

Comment: This method can be expanded to search for any html ending tag such as b. A regular expression might make it faster, but the underlying principle remains the same.

Comment: As you don't know what potential HTML tags are in the text up-front this technique won't work so well :/

Answer (score -6):

Expanding on the previous post I would do something like this for something quick and simple:

```
import sys, os

if os.path.exists("file.html"):
    checkfile=open("file.html", mode="r", encoding="utf-8")
    ishtml = False
    for line in checkfile:
        line=line.strip()
        if line == "</html>"
            ishtml = True
    if ishtml:
        print("This is an html file")
    else:
        print("This is not an html file")
```

Comment: what about partials and what about non-styled html (i.e. </html> is not the whole line) (ok, here one can use "contains" instead of "==")

Comment: You're right didn't think of that, in that case I would probably modify 
    *if line == "</html>":*
to
    *if "</html>" in line:*